# C, for loop: unexplained change of the index value from 0 to the end condition number

Tags: c, for-loop

In the following code the value of "index" jump from 0 to 10... and I have not idea how this is possible...

```
int main()
{

    int length = 10;
    int index = 0;
    printf("index is %d\n", index);
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++);
    {
        printf("index is %d\n", index);
    }

    printf("answer\n");


   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
index is 0
index is 11
answer
```

Comment: The problem is here `for (index = 0; index < length; index++);` the for-loop has an empty body and just increments the index to 10. then the code below is executed. remove the `;` after the for-loop

Comment: It's always the simple things.  Here I am, digging into printf format strings.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
int main()
{    
    int length = 10;
    int index = 0;
    printf("index is %d\n", index);

    for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
      // empty loop
    }

    {
        printf("index is %d\n", index);
    }

    printf("answer\n");    

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You need tot remove the `;` here:

```
for (index = 0; index < length; index++);
                                        ^ remove this semicolon
```

Comment: That seems to explain reaching 10 without printing (well-spotted by the way). But does it explain the 11?

Comment: @Yunnosch no it doesn't, I suspect a failed copy/paste operation here.

Comment: I posted the code in a code-bin thing and my result was 10.

Comment: It is 10, [see here](https://ideone.com/oqCgg5)... Copy paste error!?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Plausible explanation. OP can you confirm?

Comment: OP said "In the following code the value of "index" jump from 0 to 10...", so I guess he failed writing the output `index is 11`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the semicolon after foor loop
for (index = 0; index < length; index++)**;**
in this form it does not execute the next statement in curly braces which you probably expect to do.